# LectureNotes: "Cannot create custom app directory, will use default app directory!"

Tags: applications

I use [LectureNotes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acadoid.lecturenotes&hl=en_US) on my [Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2016)](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/tablets/galaxy-tab-a-10-1-p580/SM-P580NZKATPA/); my device has `Android 8.1.0`.  I want to store files from the app on my external SD card, but keep getting the error in the title.  Here's what I've done:

1. I gave the app storage permissions.
2. Navigated to `Settings > Storage > App directory setup`.
3. Enter `/storage/0000-0000/LectureNotes/` in the custom app directory.

I keep getting the error `Cannot create custom app directory, will use default app directory!`, and can't figure out why this is.  Surfing the web and this site yields solutions which do not work on my device (e.g. ).

What am I doing wrong?  Should I be using a different path?

---

**Note**: I'm friendly with Linux, but a novice with the Android file system.  In answers, please provide (1) a solution to my problem, (2) an explanation, and (3) an explanation of why I'm running into this problem (if it's not too much trouble).  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write access to the external sdcard requires to use a special API by the app. And you have to grant access to the app explicitly (or in detail the has to request permission and you have to select the correct folder and grant it to the app). When you first encounter this it is very confusing.

Comment: @Robert Does this mean I can't accomplish this from outside the app?  I.e. Something has to be changed in the app's source code?

Comment: Regarding the permission I am not sure that may be possible via adb, too, but the permission is useless unless the app uses the Storage Access Framework to write the files. Only using SAF you can write files to the external ad-card. The only alternative would be to modify some system settings and allow every app full sd-card access (requires rooted device).